# Problems hiding a TabPage in my Main Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tabpage

I'm struggling with a simple show/hide function for my main form. I needed to work through different permits, where:

1. If I start my app and no one has logged on, the tab page should dissapear,
2. At the moment someone has logged on, should show the tab with their respective permits.

I found an answer at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713526/hiding-blocking-tabs-using-windows-forms-in-c-sharp) and I tried to apply it, but it seems that I miss something.

My code for the function is the followed

```
public void TabPage1Permission(frmMain formMain, profile myProfile)
{
    if (myProfile.Equals(profile.Visitor))
    {
        formMain.tabPage1.Enabled = false;
        formMain.tabPage1.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        formMain.tabPage1.Enabled = true;
        formMain.tabPage1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

In this code:

- profile is an enum with three values, in which only the value "visitor" doesn't have permits to see TabPage1.

  public enum profile { Visitor = 0, Administrator = 1, Editor = 2 };
- The function that you see is called in my start code of the main form.
- This function is in a class apart from the main form which I use to administrate the permits according to the requirements of my app.
- I have changed the modifiers in all components inside my main form so I can use them out of the main code class of the form.

Comment: Share that Image here.... and debug the code ....

Comment: Use Threading concept with in a time Interval.. and Call the function with use of Thread.

Comment: @AravindSrinivas Do you refer about the main form? The code is debugged, it runs well but the program does not hide my tabPage as expected.

Comment: @MarialvyMartínez what's the type of `profile`? show its definition

Comment: @KingKing I edited my question but I think you didn't read complete the description of the code... I said there that profile is an enum ;)

Comment: @MarialvyMartínez you can't hide the `TabPage`, just can disable it.

Comment: @MarialvyMartínez when you **disable** it, all the controls on the tabpage will be disabled BUT you can still navigate to/from it.

Comment: Are you trying in same form or different form

Comment: @SenthilKumar not on the same form, but on a class in wich i pass my frmMain as a parameter.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Thanks to the comments of @KingKing, I have found another option in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552579/how-to-hide-tabpage-from-tabcontrol) and I adapted it as it follows:

```
public void TabPage1Permission(frmMain formMain, profile myProfile, int index)
{
    if (myProfile.Equals(profile.Visitor))
    {
        formMain.tabControl.TabPages.Remove(formMain.TabPage1);
    }
    else
    {
        formMain.tabControl.TabPages.Insert(index, formMain.TabPage1);
    }
}
```

With this I check if the user is a visitor or not and then I show the tab or not in my main TabControl

Comment: This can be used **in your specific case** but not in **general case** when we **want to keep the order** of the `TabPage`. You may also want to look at the method `Insert` instead of `Add` to *show* the tabpage at the specified index.